# The attachable property 'MergedDictionaries' was not found in type 'ResourceDictionary'

Tags: c#, wpf, mergeddictionaries

```
<Application x:Class="mahaapswpf.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I'm trying to use a MahApps.Metro Framework and I'm supposed to include this in my App.xaml, but I get "Nested properties are not supported: ResourceDictionaries.MergedDictionaries" error and "The attachable property "MergedDictionaries" was not found in type "ResourceDictionary".

I've tried everything but still can't fix this. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're missing the tag that actually creates a `ResourceDictionary` instance:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            ...
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```